# Jumbotron image not setting, image URL found but shows a caution symbol

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

The Jumbotron background image isn't being set.

html file:
...

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

...

style.css:

```
 .jumbotron {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0px;
      background-image: "https://pi-ltsp.net/images/desktop-background.png";
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

... 
(or)

```
.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-image: "../img/example.jpg";
  background-size: cover;
}
```

folder structure:
css/style.css
img/
js/
.html files

I considered the possibility that my URL is wrong but it doesn't work for local as well as images off the internet. 
Using Dev Tools, I've identified that the image is striked off with a yellow caution symbol next to it.

How may I get the background-image to be set for jumbotron. 
Thank you.

Comment: background-image:url(" here comes url");

Comment: Check this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
.jumbotron{
 background-image: url("img/file-name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were having a small [syntax error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image). Correct syntax should be:

> **background-image: url("image_path");**

What you had was `background-image: "image_path";`

Check out below snippet for the working demo.

```css
.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-image: url("http://pi-ltsp.net/images/desktop-background.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

h1,
p {
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```